# how to remove delimiter from first column?

Tags: shell, csv, awk, cut

I'm having a **Employee.csv** file. Downloaded from [this link](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?dsrcid=986724). It look like [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNcaM.png). **As you can see that in  1st column Name is containing delimiter(,)**.

```
NAME,JOB TITLE,DEPARTMENT,EMPLOYEE ANNUAL SALARY,ESTIMATED ANNUAL SALARY MINUS FURLOUGHS
```

This is column header. Below is the data.

```
"AARON,  ELVIA J",WATER RATE TAKER,WATER MGMNT,$81000.00,$73862.00
"AARON,  JEFFERY M",POLICE OFFICER,POLICE,$74628.00,$74628.00
```

As above data is having five columns I want to read data in five columns.

1. `AARON ELVIA J` as first column (Name).
2. `WATER RATE TAKER` as second column (JOB TITLE)
3. `WATER MGMNT` as third column (DEPARTMENT)
4. `81000` as fourth column (EMPLOYEE ANNUAL SALARY)
5. `73862.00` as fifth column (ESTIMATED ANNUAL SALARY MINUS FURLOUGHS)

Same for the rest of rows, because at the end I have to load the data into a table with five columns as stated above.

How can read the whole data into five columns?

Comment: The emp name is in `"` for this reason. Most parsers are clever to ignore any delimiters in apostrophes...

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using awk?

Comment: Post text samples , not links to offsite resources.

Comment: Look into https://github.com/johnkerl/miller

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csv/info

Comment: @shuham tiwari. Just out of curiosity, why did you choose to revert the formatting that I did and make part of your question nearly illegible? Was it just an edit conflict?

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry but I edited my question after Ed Morton comment. I really don't know what are you talking about? If you have anything else to ask you can ask in comments. And thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks @ismail Moghul for your help and sharing your resources

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do `awk -F"," { print $1 } filename.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use " as delimiter and use cut

```
cat filename | cut -d '"' -f2
```

Comment: I already tried this but it is not working. It's returning whole row as output

Comment: @shubhamtiwari I think you are missing out something. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to remove first comma.

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/\(".*\),\(.*".*\)/\1 \2/' infile.txt
```